# How to toggle radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just want to toggle between radio buttons. The value starts with null.

If 0, first checkbox selected, second unselected

if 1, second checkbox selected, first unselected

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <span>Value: {{vm.value}}</span> <br>

  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.value" value={{vm.value}}
         ng-click="vm.value = 0" ng-checked="vm.value == 0"
         ng-init="vm.value = null" />

  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.value" ng-click="vm.value = 1"
         value={{vm.value}} ng-checked="vm.value == 1" />
</div>
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to add the same name as a property to each input type radio. Add `name="myValues"` to each input as an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Theres no need to use `ng-click` and `ng-checked`.

- You have to set the name of each radio to the same, like `name="myRadios"` in the example below
- You have to set the `value` to `0` or `1` instead of `{{vm.value}}` or bind it to your wanted data.

  (*Your `ng-model="vm.value" value="{{vm.value}}"` makes no sense, because `ng-model=` is the part where you want to store the value and `value=` is the part where the value comes from.*)

---

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <span>Value: {{vm.value}}</span> <br>

  <input type="radio" name="myRadios" ng-model="vm.value" value="0" ng-init="vm.value = null" />

  <input type="radio" name="myRadios" ng-model="vm.value" value="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: I can't hardcode the value. This comes from the db

Comment: @Tiago: the value is irrelevant to the answer, the important part is that the `name` attribute-value is the same for each related `<input>`.

Comment: To bind your value to the data from your db you could use `value="{{yourvalue}}"` or [`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue). But note that your `value="{{vm.value}}"` makes no sense, because you want to store the selection into `vm.value` and not to get the values from it.

Answer (score -1):

give your inputs same name!

```
<input type="radio" name="radio ng-model="vm.value" value={{vm.value}}
       ng-click="vm.value = 0" ng-checked="vm.value == 0"
       ng-init="vm.value = null" />

<input type="radio" name="radio ng-model="vm.value"
       ng-click="vm.value = 1" value={{vm.value}}
       ng-checked="vm.value == 1" />
```